# gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory, on Windows, using VS code

Tags: c++, c

I try to compile a cpp file with this header:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
```

I work with MSYS2, so both the compiler and the gtk library are installed through it. The cpp compiler path is:
`D:\msys\usr\bin\cpp.exe`

and here is the VS code include path additions, which I supplied to the IntelliSense Configurations page under "include path":

```
D:\msys\mingw64\include\gtk-2.0\**
D:\msys\mingw64\include\**
D:\msys\mingw64\lib\**
D:\msys\usr\include\**
```

and I have gtk etc. in the include folder. I actually installed three different versions of gtk, 2-4.
Before I added them to the include path, I got an error like "cannot open source file", and after adding them I get the
`fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory`
error. gtk/gtk.h is located just inside gtk-2.0. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to supply those additional include paths to the compiler.

Comment: I did that, I edited the post now to clarify this.

Comment: Please show your compiler options. I would guess you only told VS Code where to look for the files but did not tell the compiler.

Comment: "Obviously, gtk/gtk.h is located just inside gtk-2.0." Did you check where it is or what do you mean by "obviously"?

Comment: You're using the wrong compiler. Most often you don't want `/usr/bin/gcc` (or `/usr/bin/cpp`). You want `/mingw64/bin/gcc`. Uninstall the `gcc` packate and install `mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`. See [How to install MinGW-w64 and MSYS2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075).

Comment: Again, you need to supply those additional include paths to the compiler. *"IntelliSense Configurations page"* has nothing to do with compiler, it is used for syntax highlighting.